# Kafka Connect Cassandra source not fetching data for timeuuid field

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect, cassandra-3.0

All, I am using Lenses cassandra source connector for kafka 1.0.0. I have done all the setup as mentioned on quick start. And it is running also. But the issue is my connector is not fetching data as soon i provide initial offset in my config file. On console I am getting

```
INFO message for query : "SELECT account_sid,datetime,price,request,response FROM testdb.testtable WHERE datetime > maxTimeuuid(?) AND datetime <= minTimeuuid(?) ALLOW FILTERING executing with bindings (2018-01-01T08:00:00Z, 2018-01-01T11:07:54Z)"
```

while executing this query seperately on my casandra table i am getting the result.  Please suggest what went wrong.  Advance thanks for any kind of help.

Below is configuration file:

```
{  
  "name":"cassandra-source",
  "config":{  
    "tasks.max":"1",
    "connector.class":"com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.source.CassandraSourceConnector",
    "connect.cassandra.contact.points":"abc.test.com",
    "connect.cassandra.port":9042,
    "connect.cassandra.username":"user",
    "connect.cassandra.password":"password",
    "connect.cassandra.key.space":"testdb",
    "connect.cassandra.initial.offset":"2018-01-01 00:00:00.0000000Z",
    "connect.cassandra.kcql":"INSERT INTO testtable SELECT account_sid,datetime,price,request,response FROM carrier_lookup_list PK datetime INCREMENTALMODE=TIMEUUID",
    "connect.progress.enabled":true
  }
}
```

Comment: can you post the log for this specific part?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if the timezone from where you are running your connector is same as of your database. Sometimes it may happen that you provided correct time in config file but your process is running with different timezone (`-Duser.timezone=UTC`).